# How to get pasted value from Reactjs onPaste event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if i have an Reactjs input text element with onPaste event assigned to it, how could I get the pasted value in the response?

at the moment what i get in the console is a SyntheticClipboardEvent with all properties as null. I read that the console.log is a async checker so thats why the majority of values are null as they are looking ahead.

However I am wondering how to get the value.

Cheers

Comment: @IshantSolanki what is the problem with the blow answer? here is a  [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h7ba8tx/)

Comment: @evgenifotia it has limited browser support

Answer (score 80):

```
onPaste: function(e) {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
},
```

Comment: when I use this, it gives me more than one value from the clipboard

Answer (score 17):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/types

> The formats are Unicode strings giving the type or format of the data,
>   generally given by a MIME type. Some values that are not MIME types
>   are special-cased for legacy reasons (for example "text").

example:

```
onPaste: function(e) {
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/html'));
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/rtf'));

    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('Url'));
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/uri-list'));
    console.log(e.clipboardData.getData('text/x-moz-url'));
}
```

Comment: e doesn't work with paste event on IE. Need to use window.

Answer (score 8):

Here is maybe a simpler "no paste" example using React hooks

```
export default function NoPasteExample() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState("");
  const [pasted, setPasted] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (!pasted) {
      setVal(e.target.value);
    }
    setPasted(false);
  };

  const handlePaste = () => {
    setPasted(true);
  };
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField
          value={val}
          onPaste={handlePaste}
          onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w61eo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

the data can be found on `clipboardData`, and parsed to string as follows:

```
event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsString(text=>{
  // do something
})
```

Answer (score -1):

**For me this is quick and worked.**

onPaste event fires before the input's value is changed.

> So we need to use e.persist()

```
<input 
   onPaste={(e)=>{
    e.persist();
    setTimeout(()=>{ this.handleChange(e)},4)}
   }
   value={this.state.value}/>
```

Comment: e.preventDefault() is the right way to fix the problem you described

Answer (score -3):

first include Facebook DataTransfer module:

```
var DataTransfer = require('fbjs/lib/DataTransfer');
```

then you can do:

```
onPaste: function (evt) {
       var data = new DataTransfer(evt.clipboardData);

       var text = data.getText();
       var html = data.getHTML();
       var files = data.getFiles();
},
```

you welcome ;)

Comment: There is no need to include an additional module simply to receive data from the clipboard, as this is possible through vanilla JS with no dependencies.